# Object properties updating between instances C#

Tags: c#, async-await, mvvm-light

I have got 4 instances of a service class within a WPF application that is updating all 4 instances when one of the complex properties change, the same changes are applied to all the instances.
The class looks like this:

```
public class ExampleClass
{
    private IEnumerable<SomeComplexType> _status;
    public int InstanceNumber { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SomeComplexType> Status
    {
        get { return _status; }
        set { _status = value; }
    }

    public Task DoSomeWork()
    {
        var t = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var random = new Random();
            int i = 1;
            foreach (var item in Status)
            {
                item.SomeValue = random.NextDouble();
                item.ItemNumber = (InstanceNumber*i);
                i++;
            }
            UpdateInterface();
        });
        return t;
    }

    public void UpdateInterface()
    {
        var message = new UpdateMessage {InstanceNumber = InstanceNumber, Status = Status};
        Messenger.Default.Send(message);
    }
}
```

With the supporting types being similar to the following:

```
    class SomeComplexType
{
    public double SomeValue { get; set; }
    public int ItemNumber { get; set; }
}

class  UpdateMessage
{
    public int InstanceNumber { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SomeComplexType> Status { get; set; }
}
```

Now when the *DoSomeWork()* method is called on instance 1, it works as expected. 
Same when the *DoSomeWork()* method is then called on instance 2, but after instance 2 has updated, the *UpdateInterface()* function on instance 1 returns the status value of instance 2, even though the correct instance number is returned.

Can anyone explain this behavior?

The calling code is a simple function triggered by a button press:

```
public ICommand OnTestClickCommand
{
    get { return _onTestClickCommand ?? (_onTestClickCommand = new RelayCommand(ButtonTestClick); }
}

private async void ButtonTestClick()
{
    await ExampleClass.DoSomeWork;
}
```

EDIT:
The problem was in the ctor of each class, which looked like this:

```
    public ExampleClass(SomeDefaultClass default)
    {
        Status = default.Status;
    }
```

The same default variable was passed in when creating each instance. Should have included that in the original ask. This only passes the reference as stated in the comments.

Comment: Can you show us the calling code

Comment: Keep in mind, passing an object between other classes only passes a reference. For example, creating an object in class 1 and passing it to class 2 would be the same as me handing you a ball (the ball isnt duplicated)

Comment: @Takarii Your comment actually led me to the solution. I declared the value for _Status_ in the constructor and set a = to the same default object for all instances. This set all the instances' memory reference to the exact same object -> the default object. Threading 101 I guess

Comment: I had the exact same confusion once upon a time. Glad you solved it.